# Is the Coraline movie trying to make a point that people should have freedom?

Tags: trope, coraline

I know it was originally a book and I'm wondering whether the original story was trying to make a point that people should have freedom.

In the Coraline movie, the main character Coraline went into a new and different world. She had no problem with the other people having buttons instead of eyes. Yet when they tried to make her sew buttons over her eyes, she had a real big problem with that.

It seems like she thought they should be in charge of themselves and run their life what ever way they want and she had no problem until they started telling her how to run her life.

Comment: No, you should have button eyes.

Comment: Lol. She has a huge problem with them having button eyes.

Answer (score -2):

You would be hard-pressed to find an author arguing that people *shouldn't* have freedom.

If Coraline is about freedom, it is the adolescent sense of the word - finding yourself, learning who you are in relation to your parents, exploring the frightening world of adulthood.

Comment: Could you explain why you think Coraline is like freedom in this aspect?

Comment: *You would be hard-pressed to find an author arguing that people shouldn't have freedom.* - Nobody suggested that Coraline is making an anti-freedom argument. You'd be hard-pressed to find an author arguing against love too, but movies about love are everywhere.

Comment: I thought they were maybe using how Coraline thinks to make the point, that the people in the other world were not crazy until they started trying to make her sow buttons over her eyes after which they were considered crazy.